# Passing Private Class to Form

Tags: c#, private

I have some minor experience using private classes using Murach's C# book, but I am still very much a novice. I am trying to create my own project which consists of a "Patient Id" "Name" "Weight" and then a equation for recommended daily protein intake (weight * .86). This eventually will be made into a basic database, however, right now I am struggling to even display the results. Furthermore, the calculation for daily protein intake will not work in the class I made.

Here is my class code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Form1
{
public class Intake
{
    private string name;
    private int patientId;
    private int weight;
    //private int proteinIntake = weight * .86;


    //Constuctor
    public Intake() { }

    //Overload Constructor
    public Intake(string name, int patientId, int weight)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.PatientId = patientId;
        this.Weight = weight;


    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
        }
    }
    public int PatientId
    {
        get
        {
            return patientId;
        }
        set
        {
            patientId = value;
        }
    }
    public int Weight
    {
        get
        {
            return weight;
        }
        set
        {
            weight = value;
        }
    }


    public string GetDisplayText(string sep) =>
        name + patientId + sep + weight;
}
}
```

Here is my form code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Form1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static Intake intake = null;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Intake intake = new Intake(txtName.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txtPatientId.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtWeight.Text) );

     //obviously does not work  MessageBox.Show("Name: " + intake.name);





    }


}
}
```

And, if it matters, here is my ugly form [image: My Ugly Form]

Comment: Doing `MessageBox.Show("Name: " + intake.name);` won't work, but doing `MessageBox.Show("Name: " + intake.Name);` should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand very well your question, I haven't read your mentioned book, but from what I see, your Intake class is not private, so the only problem is that you try to display a private field in your MessageBox, and so, if you uncomment the statement, it doesn't compile at all.
So if you want to display the name of your instance in the MessageBox:

```
MessageBox.Show("Name: " + intake.Name);
```

will work for sure.
The only thing you have to remember(in this case) is the difference between private fieds and public properties.
The private fields are accessible only inside your class, the public properties are accessible by all your program.

> ## [Accessibility Levels (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx)
>
> **public**
>
> *Access is not restricted.*
>
> ---
>
> **protected**
>
> *Access is limited to the containing class or types derived from the containing class.*
>
> ---
>
> **internal**
>
> *Access is limited to the current assembly.*
>
> ---
>
> **protected internal**
>
> *Access is limited to the current assembly or types derived from the containing class.*
>
> ---
>
> **private**
>
> *Access is limited to the containing type.*

Answer (score 2):

Fyi: in the "intake" class, you can override the ToString()

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("Name: {0}, PatientId: {1}, Weight: {2}", Name, PatientId, Weight);
}
```

And then u can use

```
MessageBox.Show(intake.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Intake class, add the GetProteinIntake() method:

```
public class Intake
{
    ... your existing code ....

    public double GetProteinIntake()
    {
        return weight * 0.86;
    }
}
```

In your form, replace your btnCalculate_Click event with:

```
private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Intake intake = new Intake(txtName.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txtPatientId.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtWeight.Text));
    txtProtein.Text = intake.GetProteinIntake().ToString();
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I tried using this, but got back
"Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'double' to 'string'"                 I would like to assign it to my textbox, which is would be "txtProtein.Text"

Comment: Oh, you should change the `public int` to `public double` (wasn't paying attention to numeric type), and then you can use `intake.GetProteinIntake().ToString()` to assign it to the textbox.

Comment: intake.GetProteinIntake().ToString(txtProtein.Text); Still doesn't calculate it. Any idea as to why?

Comment: Heh sorry... that would be `txtProtein.Text = intake.GetProteinIntake().ToString()`

Comment: That doesn't work either... Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: No, just nothing shows up in the Recommend Daily Protein Intake box at all

Comment: I'll edit my answer to make sure you have everything in the right place.  Give me just a sec...

Comment: If it doesn't give you the correct results, put a breakpoint on the btnCalculate_Click event and make sure the right values are getting passed in and passed back.